# Program to copy and get sizes for files, filtered by filetype blacklist

Tags: windows-7, file-management, file-synchronization, file-format

Problem: I have a a directory that is several GBs, I need to get the total filesize and copy the files to another folder, filtering out certain file types/extensions.

I'm using Smart Copy Tool, right now, but it uses a white list.

Requirements: Compatible with Windows 7, free or free with trial. I only have to use this for a short time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Free Commander](http://freecommander.com/)

Free Commander has a filter tool to exclude certain files by name, date, size, attribute, or by regular expressions. Here is an example of a filter excluding files with sizes over 1GiB:

[image]

<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

After applying such a filter, you could easily select the remaining files and copy them like you normally do.

Free Commander is **free of charge** and is **compatible with Windows 7**

Answer (score 0):

TreeSize Free scans network drives and locally synchronized cloud shares (except on Windows servers and within a Windows domain) - just like TreeSize Personal!

The column view presents more detailed information for each file and folder. Here you will find the size or number of files as well as the last access date and the owner (and other useful facts).

http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Answer (score 0):

Use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/). `<Ctrl-L>` gives you the total size for selected files/directories. You can sort your selection, edit it, and a ton of other features.

**In your case specifically:**

(Preliminary) size of entire directory:
Hit 'Ctrl-L' on the directory

[image]

Now go into that directory and *search* all files, unlimited depth:

[image]

Feed to listbox:

[image]

Gives you:

[image]

Now select all (make sure you have *Configuration/Options/Operation/Select files only* checked), then deselect the file types (assuming that what you describe as *types* can be matched with *extensions*) you don't want:

[image]

which leaves you with

[image]

and now you can copy these to the left side.

Free with a nag screen, or $44 / €32 for a lifetime license.

Comment: Total Commander is nice, but I don't see a way to blacklist certain files. In `Show > Custom` I can filter what filetypes I want, but not what I don't want. Do you know where it is?

Comment: You can reduce your selection with a deselect on certain file extensions - don't know if that matches your 'filetype' description.